# link_to "about",about_path showing the error in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am working in Ruby on rails.. i am new to this..

i have used a line

```
   <%= link_to "about",about_path %>

    which throws me a error as,

    undefined local variable or method `about_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb5f5baa8>
```

i am having the page about.html under app/views/pages/

please give some suggestions of why i am getting like this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is looking for what is called a named route. You need to define these in `config/routes.rb`. In addition you will need some controller and action to handle them. See this [post](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2009/08/22/static-pages-in-rails.html) describing a very simple way to handle static pages by way of illustration.

To get the `about_path` named route, then you would add this to `routes.rb`

```
map.about "/pages/about", :controller => "pages", :action => "show", :id => "about"
```

Then add your about page contents to a file called `app/views/pages/about.html.erb`

Finally:

```
$ rake routes
```

tells you all of the named routes defined for your application and what they do

Comment: @John Topley. Thanks for fixing those typos

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem using the Hartl's tutorial. Here is what I did.

When asking `rake routes`, I have :

```
tomsihap-MBP:sample_app tomsihap$ rake routes
              Prefix Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
                root GET  /                               static_pages#home
   static_pages_help GET  /static_pages/help(.:format)    static_pages#help
  static_pages_about GET  /static_pages/about(.:format)   static_pages#about
static_pages_contact GET  /static_pages/contact(.:format) static_pages#contact
```

Then the correct path is :

```
<%= link_to "About",   static_pages_about_path  %>
```

And not `<%= link_to "About", about_path  %>` as suggested by Hartl's guide.

EDIT :

Ok now I understand. That is because routes were defined like that :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
root 'static_pages#home'
get 'static_pages/help' 
get 'static_pages/about' 
get 'static_pages/contact'
```

Instead of, later explained into the tutorial :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
root 'static_pages#home' 
get 'help' => 'static_pages#help' 
get 'about' => 'static_pages#about' 
get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
```

Using this way, the correct path now is :

```
<%= link_to "About", about_path  %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess your about page is "static". Check this..

routes.rb

```
# rails 2.3.x
map.about "/pages", :controller => 'pages', :action => 'about'
```

Controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def about # not needed, only for "tidiness"

  end
end
```

... and your erb file have to be here: Views\pages\about.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

Is in your routes.rb something like map.resources :about ?

If you don't know why it should be there or what is that, read about RESTful Routing on [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restful-routing-the-rails-default).

Comment: This would only make sense if you have a model called "about". He just wants to route a static page ...